# How can i use PUT method to edit Serialized data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I created an **edit** function to edit  username of user.

```
def edit(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        data = request.POST
        s = UserSerializer(data=data)
        u = s.is_valid()
        if u:
            s.update(request.user.username,request.POST['username'])
            return JsonResponse(
                {
                    'message' : 'profile edited!'
                },status=201
            )
    else:
        return JsonResponse(
            {
                'message' : 'you are not login!'
            },status=401
        )
```

I don't know where PUT should be used and also how can I use `update()`  .

and this is my serializer class :

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'username','email','password'
        )

    def validate_password(self,password):
        password = make_password(password)
        return password

    def update(self,isinstance, validated_data):
        instance.username = validated_data.get('username', instance.username)
        instance.email = validated_data.get('email', instance.email)
        return instance
```

Comment: Hope this section will guide you https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Django rest framework [APIView class](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/), you should use from put function instead of edit:

```
def put(request):
    ...
```

to use serializer, in your view function, use [`serializers.save()` function](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances):

```
def put(request):
    ....
    s.save()
```

the save function, based on the view function will call update (for put function), create (for post function), and destroy (for delete function).
when you want to instantiate from the serializer class, you must pass the model object as `instance` and data as `data` attribute. in summary your view function will be something like this:

```
  class YourView(APIView)
      def put(request):
         if request.user.is_authenticated:
            s = UserSerializer(instance=request.user, data=request.POST)
            if s.is_valid():
                s.save()
                return Response(
                    {
                        'message': 'profile edited!'
                    }, status=201
                )
        else:
            return Response(
                {
                    'message' : 'you are not login!'
                },status=401
            )
```

Comment: where to create this function ? serializer or views?

Comment: and i call put  function in my urls?

Comment: @AmirrezaRiahi the put function will call automatically by APIView class based on the request method